# How to reopen application after login

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm an android developer. in android, when user login in application, I will re-open the `MainActivity` class ( controller ) to refresh some views.

in iOS applications, how to do this scenario ?

Comment: U need to set that view as rootviewcontroller after Logging in

Answer (score 1):

You can reopen you default/`LandingViewController`.
Suppose you have a View Controller with name `LandingViewController`
When you successfully logged in all you need is to re instantiate the `LandingViewController`
In AppDelegate class make a function with name

```
func userDidLoggedIn(){
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)//Replace Main With your own storyboard name containing LandingViewController
    let landingViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LandingViewControllerIdentifier")//Pass your LandingViewController Identier that you have set in your storyboard file.
    guard let subviews = self.window?.subviews else {
        return
    }
    for view in subviews {
        view.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    self.window?.rootViewController = landingViewController
}
```

Now Simply Call this Function where ever in the entire project like this In your case write below lines in the completion block of login request API.

```
let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
delegate. userDidLoggedIn()
```

Comment: what is `self.window?` ?

Comment: A window object provides the backdrop for your app’s user interface and provides important event-handling behaviors. Windows do not have any visual appearance of their own, but they are crucial to the presentation of your app’s views. It holds your view to make it visible to the screen. As AppDelegate is a singleton class so there will be a single window object which is your default applications window.

Comment: How can I initial it ? because I got this message : `value of type 'LoginController'has no member 'window'`

Comment: You need to create the method in AppDelegate class and call that method in your viewController.
By creating an object of AppDelegate and then invoke that method.

Answer (score 1):

Once user login, you can change your rootviewcontroller like this:

```
var nav_VC: UIViewController?
func onSuccessfulLogin()
    {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        nav_VC = nil
        if nav_VC == nil {
            nav_VC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "home_nav")
        }
        self.window?.rootViewController = nav_VC
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
```